# how to set values from database into the textfield

Tags: java

```
 private void btgetinvActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "REMITTANCE ID IS VALID!");
        try {
            DBUtil util = new DBUtil();
            Connection con = util.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select bk_det.rm_id from bk_det WHERE dbo.bk_det.rm_id = ?");
            ResultSet rs;
            String rm = tf_rmid.getText().trim();
            stmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(rm));
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                int i = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("box_no"));
                tfbrname.setText(rs.getString(i));
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());

        }
    }
```

I am actually trying to search value from my database table called dbo.bk_det. I am taking the value of WHERE from my textfield tf_rmid. Everything goes on well without error but once i insert the rm_id and click on button btgetinv it says 123 which is my rm_id is out of range cant understand where the error is and what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the following statements:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("box_no"));
tfbrname.setText(rs.getString(i));
```

The first statement won't work the way you want because there's no column named "box_no" in the select clause.  It will throw an exception.  Let's assume you change the code to have box_no in the select clause.  Then, the second statement will try to retrieve the nth column where the column is the value of box_no.  I think you just want:

```
tfbrname.setText(rs.getString("box_no"));
```

Again, the above only will work if your SELECT statement includes box_no in the field list.

Answer (score 1):

`rs.next()` returns false if it does not contain any more records. So if you want to behave something when no records found, you have to check record count.

for example,

```
int recordCount = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
    recordCount++;
    int i = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("box_no"));
    tfbrname.setText(rs.getString(i));
}
if(recordCount == 0) {
    // do something : report an error or log
}
```

for further information, see [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29)